# Google Spreadsheet: Array formula if/and to return "No" if 3 previous cells are blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't post a link due to sensitive information, but I can provide the structure:

```
|Id    |PT/DOT   |Primary Employee |From   |To   |Per x Days  |Frequency Data Complete? |
 ------ --------- ----------------- ------- ----- ------------ -------------------------
```

Those are the Column Headers. In Column A, B, and C there are text values. In D, E, & F there are either number values or blank values, dependent on whether the min frequency (From), max frequency (To), and Period (Per x Days) has been completed by the primary employee or not. Column G should provide a "Yes" or "No" value if all 3 frequency-related columns are not blank.

Simple version of this would be `=if(and(D1<>"",E1<>"",F1<>""),"Yes","No")`. That works in the simple version, but,I need it to autofill down for the number of rows of data because they change dynamically based on scripting.

Next step I tried was `=arrayformula(if(and(D2<>"",E2<>"",F2<>""),"Yes","No"))` which doesn't autofill down (continue) because it's not really an array.

I modified it to `=arrayformula(if($D2:$F="","No","Yes"))`, which fills down to the end of the data, but it does not return a single `Yes` or `No` to Column G, but instead `Yes` or `No` for each of the 3 columns to G, H, and I. I could hide these columns and do a `=countif("Yes")` on J, but I'm still in the same boat with autofilling down.

I can do it with a script that sets a formula in column G, but that adds another run of scripting and another trigger to the process, when I would like to just keep a running tab on whether or not D, E, and F are complete.

I'm not really sure what the easiest method is here. I really need this to autofill down without additional effort from the user. onEdit script might be the only choice, but I'd rather not have to do that.

I've tried everything I can think of, and have searched this topic until any remotely relevant link is purple. I can't find anything that I could even modify to get to the same ends.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple way is to use the * operator, which simulates a logical AND over an array:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((D2:D<>"")*(E2:E<>"")*(F2:F<>""),"Yes","No"))`

Comment: Ahh!  I tried that, but I didn't wrap the ranges themselves in parentheses.  I did it like this =Arrayformula(if(D2:D<>""*E2:E<>""*F2:F<>""),"Yes","No"))  I was so close!

Answer (score 0):

use `ISBLANK` function with an `IF`

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F1)=FALSE;"YES";IF(ISBLANK(E1)=FALSE;"YES";IF(ISBLANK(D1)=FALSE;"YES";"NO")))
```